# How execute MyBatis query with more than one variable

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm having a problem with MyBatis execute query, I'm triying to execute sending 3 variables but I get an error, I know that this is the problem because when I only send one variable it works. I find that all the people send objects instead of variables when they have more than one, but I don't want to create an object because I have multiple mybatis executes and I can't create an object for eveyone because they have different variables.

So there's anyway to fix it? I can send 2 variables? Or I must create an object?

Here's the code

```
public List consultaRepresentacions(final int representat, final int representant, final String app){

    List representacions = myBatisTemplate.execute(ReproDao.class, new MyBatisDaoCallback<List>() {
        @Override
        public List execute(MyBatisDao dao) {
            return ((ReproDao) dao).consultaRepros(representat, representant, app);
        }
    });

    return representacions;
}
```

Thanks in advise.

Comment: Please, show the mapper method signature and the xml mapping if you use xml.

Comment: Is it a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968088/how-can-i-pass-multiple-parameters-and-use-them ? Delete this question if that is the case